# Adding a "notes/comments" column to a read only list?

Tags: 2013, permissions, column

i have a read only list and i would like to add a column with edit permissions. So Far i haven't found anything concerning column level permission so can we somewhow achieve this? I can't code tho so i have no idea how to do this oob.

I thought using infopath and just hide everything and let the columns that can be edited. But my list won't be read only anymore. I could hide the quick edit option via list settings, but is it secure enough to not allow users to change any other columns?

Answer (score 1):

One way to keep your list contents read-only and have your comments column would be to create a new list with a lookup column to the original list and the contents column you wish to add. If you mark the lookup column with the "Enforce unique values" you can ensure a 1-to-1 relationship.

hope this helps.
d.

Comment: Yeah that's what you can find on google. But it's not good enough. I'll stick with my custom form and only show 1 column on the edit form.